# Displaying MySQL Data in an Unordered List Efficiently

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a skills list in MySQL and display it one by one in an unordered list in my index.php file.

Currently my method is as follows and this gives me the desired result (please note: I actually call this every time needed for every skill which is 11 - This is just number 2 & 3 for demonstrative purpose):

```
 <li><?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM skillset WHERE id = 2;";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row[skill] . "<br>";
    }
 }?></li>

 <li><?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM skillset WHERE id = 3;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row[skill] . "<br>";
    }
}?></li>
```

The method I have used works sufficiently, but obviously is not efficient as there are 15 individual skills.

Logic tells me the correct way would be to select all from "skillset" and then loop through the array, but am having trouble doing so and keep coming back to this method.

Comment: yes, you could change that query by using an `IN` clause, `id IN (2, 3)`, like so, that way you only need to make a query once

Comment: Maybe `SELECT * FROM skillset ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2` ?

Comment: after that, you could just group the array based on their id, then the foreach and markup and so on

Comment: Is `<?p>` a typo?

Comment: Sorry, typo fixed courtesy of Islam Elshobokshy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest doing something as follow (just for that example, do as you like with any other values).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM skillset WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<li>' . $row['skill'] . '<br></li>';
    }
}
```

If you have a thousand id for example, then I would suggest using `BETWEEN` like so :

```
SELECT * FROM skillset WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

Comment: in each `<li>` you need to enumerate all skillsets, `<li>(all id 2 skill sets here with each <br/>)</li>` and so on, so you'd probably need to group the array first, fetch, group by id (or category), then print the markup

Comment: @Ghost I agree that grouping by id might be necessary, but what do you mean by group the array?

Comment: you can have the choice of either having it fetched first, group them by id and put inside a container (array, ala `$array[<id here>][] = skill`), then presenting it inside a markup (`foreach with the <li>`), or you could just simply fetch and group them while printing the markup

Comment: The `GROUP BY` in the SQL is not the right solution (changed to `ORDER BY` - not to mention its a bad idea to use GROUP BY along with `SELECT *`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can see logically how this would work however I have implemented this into my code but am being left with no data displayed. I added an else statement with an error message, so presumably resultCheck is coming back as 0. Not sure why this is happening seeing as I haven't changed anything else.

Comment: @JABedford you will have to debug then. If you copy/paste the query in your phpMyAdmin or something similar, do you get any results? If you do, try to `var_dump($result)` and see what you got.

Comment: Happy to help @JABedford !